# fabricjs how to pass canvas from one page to another

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas on one page that is built using fabricjs
can i send that canvas to another page so that it retains all its objects as it is with all their properties and attributes to be same aswell.

Comment: Hi, what is another page? For another user or all for the same user. For multiple users you can use nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, just export your canvas to JSON

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
data = JSON.stringify(canvas)
```

Now you can send that data using a post request or store it in a database or whatever you want.

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(data, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/P9cEf/3/

The example uses two canvases one page, but the concept is the same.

Edit:
To download the image client side

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("c");
var image = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
window.location.href = image;
```

Comment: can u show me how to download this object as a file on client side and load functionality on client side aswell